# logstash custom patterns not parsing

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

i am facing an issue in parsing the below pattern 
the log file will have log importance in the form of == or <= or >= or << or >>
I am trying the below custom pattern. Some of the log msgs may not have this pattern, so I am using * 
(?(=<>)*)

But the log mesages are not parsing and give 'grokparsefailure'
kindly check and suggest if the above pattern is wrong.. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

below pattern is working fine.
(?[=<>]*)

the one which I used earlier and was erroring is
(?(=<>)*)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, there is a better way to handle the "some do, some don't" aspect of your log-data.

```
(?<Importance>(=<>)*)
```

That will match more than you want. To get the sense of 'sometimes':

```
((?<Importance>(=<>)*)|^)
```

This says, *match these three characters and define the field `Importance`, or leave the field unset*.

Second, you're matching specifically two characters, in combinations:

```
((?<Importance>(<|>|=){2})|^)
```

This should match two instances of any of the trio of characters you're looking for.